# Slotted ALOHA probability and efficiency

Tags: mac

Given:

There are two active nodes, A and B, in a slotted ALOHA network.

Node A transmit in each slot with probability **a** while Node B transmit
with probability **b**.

The first slot is numbered Slot 1, the second slot is numbered Slot 2, etc.

What is the probability that **Node A succeeds for the first time in Slot 6**? What is the **efficiency of the system?**

My reasoning/solution (that is incorrect):

1. For node A to succeed for the first time in slot 6, this means I need to calculate the probability (Node A succeed for the first time in slot 6) = Pr(Node A fail in slot 1,2,3,4,5) * Pr(Node A succeed in slot 6) = (1-a)(1-a)(1-a)(1-a)(1-a)a
   However this seems to be wrong, do I need to factor in node B in this case?
   Should if I need to account for node B, IP will need to calculate:
   Pr(Node A fail in slots 1-5, Node B can either succeed or fail in slots 1-5) * Pr(node A succeeds in slot 6 but node B fails)?
   If so, how do I calculate it? A bit stumped on this question.
2. Efficiency of the system can be calculated by the probability that some node succeeds in a slot? How do I calculate this when both nodes have different probabilities? I am only taught how to calculate if they have the same probability.

Comment: what does "What is the probability that Node A succeeds for the first time in Slot 6?" mean, does this mean A tries to transmit starting from slot 1 and is only successful in slot 6? Or does this mean - what is the probability of first successful packet of A being in slot 6?

Comment: @Effie the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the correct answer and what is written in answer of @Zac67 I interpret it as follows.

> Probability of X := first packet of A being transmitted successfully only in slot 6

P (X) = P ( [X1 := no packet of A is transmitted in slots 1-5] and [X2 := packet of A is transmitted in slot 6]) = /*both events are independent*/ P (X1) * P(X2) = /*all 5 slots are independent*/ P (X3 := no packet of A is transmitted in a slot)^5  *  P(X2)

P (X3) = P ([A does not transmit] or [A transmits, but there is a collision]) = P ([A does not transmit]) + P([A transmits, but there is a collision]) = (1-a) + (ab)

P (X2) = P ([A transmits but B not]) = P (A transmits) * P (B does not transmit) = a * (1-b).

Thus P(X) = (1 - a + ab)^5 * a (1 - b)

> Efficiency

If we define efficiency a the probability that there is a successful transmission in a slot, then

P ([successful transmission]) = P ([only one of A or B transmits]) = P ([A transmits but B not] or [B transmits but A not]) = /* events are mutually exclusive */ P ([A transmits but B not]) + P([B transmits but A not]) = a ( 1 - b)  + b (1 - a) = a + b - 2ab.

I am not sure how to generify (word) this formula for more than 2 systems.

Answer (score 1):

For *any* slot, the probability for a transmission attempt is *a + b*. Transmissions are successful if there's no collision. The probability for a collision - both nodes transmitting simultaneously - is *a * b*.

> What is the probability that Node A succeeds for the first time in Slot 6?

There's only one 'first time' in any slot. The probability for trying to use a slot is constant, so the slot number is irrelevant.

[edited] The probability for A's *success* is the probability for transmission *a* minus the probability for a collision: *a - a * b*

If you actually need the 'fail five times and then succeed' variant, that's *(1 - (a - a * b))<sup>5</sup> * (a - a * b)*

> What is the efficiency of the system?

That asks for whether a slot is successfully used by either node, without causing a collision: *(a - a * b) + (b - a * b) = a + b - 2 * a * b*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The solution to the answer is supposed to be [1 - a + ab]^5 * a(1-b) and a + b – 2ab for efficiency. It doesn't seem to tally though.

Comment: (a + b) * (1 - a * b). should not work, because the event of collision is not independent of transmission, so P(A and B) = P(A)*P(B) should not apply.

Comment: @Meep you could have lead with that :D

Comment: Hmm, running a little experiment, the only thing I got right is the collision probability. I guess I need to rethink... *a + b – 2ab* for efficiency seems right - *a-ab* is the probability for A to succeed, *b-ab* that for B.

Comment: Edited the answer, makes sense now - sorry for the confusion, guys!

Comment: ye, knowing how to calculate  probabilities in completely unrealistic  models is such a useful networking skill :) On the other hand letting others get some reputation should be considered charity.